# Auto-capitalizing first word in every list \item?

Tags: lists, capitalization

I'm working on a paper that deals with foreign words and a lot of diacritics. To help with this, I've created a series of macros, so that if I write \wufen it comes out as "*wǔfēn*". Usually this is mid-sentence, so that's fine. However in a few cases, I've got the following:

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \wufen something something
    \item Something \wufen something...
\end{enumerate}
```

Is there a way to force `\item`s to always capitalise the first letter? I want to see this as the result of the above:

---

• *Wǔfēn* something something

• Something *wǔfēn* something...

---

Is this possible?

I'm relatively new to LaTeX so apologies if this is a terrible question. I'm honestly not too clear on what I should be searching for, though past attempts haven't produced anything yet.

Comment: Why not make uppercase versions of your macros? `\Wufen` etc. and use these.

Comment: Why not to use unicode and get rid of these macros? _/holding the **AGAINST MACROS FOR WORDS** sign very high..._

Comment: @tohecz if you plan on saying that often you could use `\def\amfw{AGAINST MACROS FOR WORDS}` :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle As a person who often reads code of others: no, never!

Comment: @AlanMunn It kinda defeats the purpose of the shorthand then. What I'm hoping to be able to do is change all cases of the macro once, so maybe before I finish, I decide I want "wǔfen" to be "wuufen", and I only have to change it in one place. In this case the macro is for reflecting a word under a certain romanisation system and I'd like to be able to switch systems without too much trouble.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please *always* post complete documents, not just fragments.

[image]

TeX is in vertical mode at that point, so you can do:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\wufen{\ifvmode W\else w\fi ufen}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item \wufen\ something something
    \item Something \wufen\ something...
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 so kool! Would `\ifvmode\expandafter\uppercase\fi wufen` work?

Comment: @tohecz no because `uppercase` needs explict `{}` but you don't need the `\expandafter` either so you can do `\newcommand\wufen{\ifvmode \uppercase\else \lowercase\fi {w}ufen}` if you want. (you need the lowercase to remove the `{}` so as not to break any inter-letter kerns.

Comment: ok, so `\MakeUppercase` ...

Comment: @tohecz `\MakeUppercase wufen` produces `{W}ufen` so would break any kern between W and u

Comment: damn, always problems. Seems that your original one is the best. I only don't like the fact that you have to seperate the first letter of the word...

Comment: wufen wufen wufen wufen wufen wufen. `:)`

Answer (score 5):

Personally I would use uppercase versions of the macros as suggested in the comments. However, if you want to do it automatically, you could use the command `\capitalize` from the `stringstrings` package.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stringstrings}
\newcommand{\citem}{\item \capitalize}

\newcommand{\abc}{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz} % A simple macro

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Abc % for comparison
    \citem abc % capitalize 
    \citem Abc % no effect if already capitalized
    \citem \abc % works for simple macros
\end{enumerate}

\end{document
```

Comment: If you wanted something that works for "complicated macros", go for `{\item\expandafter\uppercase}` or `{\item\expandafter\capitalize}`. However, your current approach kills the optional argument to `\item`.

Comment: @tohecz: I fully agree. To save the optional argument one could do something like `\newcommand{\citem}[1][\stepcounter{enumi}\labelenumi]{\item[#1] \capitalize}`, which is quite messy. Hence +1 for 
David Carlisle's elegant solution.